# Shrinking a UIScrollView to focus on a certain page

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with horizontal pagination - similar to the weather app. Under certain circumstances, I want to prevent the user from scrolling horizontally. Simply disabling the scrolling is a little jarring - I would prefer to duplicate the experience of scrolling past  the last page - a little scrolling is permitted, but since there is no more content, the scrollview bounces back.

How might I go about implementing this? Should I be changing the contentSize of the ScrollView? How do I set up the pagination so that there is effectively one 'page' but there is still content displayed to the immediate left and right?

Comment: Just shrink the content size.

Comment: Setting the width of the content size to 1 * the width of the contents just stops scrolling altogether, with no bounce back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to always make the `UIScrollView` bounce, even with just one page, add the following line:

```
[self.scrollView setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:YES];
```

In addition to my comment about shrinking the `contentSize`, of course.

---

**EDIT:**

OK, let me first explain want we want to achieve. The User is scrolling happily between the pages in the `UIScrollView`, and suddenly, we want the `UIScrollView` to stick to the current page, **which may or may not be the first page**.

Our `UIScrollView` has the pages laid out, with each page represented by a single `UIView` or it's subclasses (it may have subviews itself):

[image: All hail MBP_RD]

Now, to perform the task explained, here is the code:

```
CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.bounds.size.width;
int currentPage = (_scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth);

[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(pageWidth, _scrollView.contentSize.height)];
// move each page to the left:
for (UIView* page in _scrollView.subviews) {
    [page setFrame:CGRectOffset(page.frame, -currentPage * pageWidth, 0)];
}
```

**NOTE:** If you have a complicated view hierarchy, just wrap it in a `UIView` that has a bounds size equal to the `_scrollView.contentSize` with **all** the pages. The rest I leave it as an exercise for the reader (I always wanted to say that xD)

Comment: Thanks. I need to also figure out how to adjust the `contentOffset`, or some other property, I think - otherwise resizing the `contentSize` forces my `UIScrollView` to scroll to a viewable portion of the content.

Comment: @BenPackard simple. First, do you just add the subviews (pages) directly to the `UIScrollView`? Or do you have a `UIView` that contains the views within the `UIScrollView`? (ie scrollView -> view -> pages) ?

Comment: The former. Each view is added as a subview of the `UIScrollView`.

Comment: @BenPackard Alright, I would have posted the code right away if it was the latter. Let me test something quick, and then post the solution.

Comment: @BenPackard Not quite quick, but meh. The edits are now live.

Comment: This is very helpful - thank you. I suspected that I would need to 'shift' the views temporarily somehow. This is very clear and concise. I will give it a shot and see where it takes me - obviously I should also perform the reverse shift when I need to re-enable the scrolling (and similarly increase the `contentSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Mazyod's answer above is probably the best one, but I had a lot of trouble returning the views to their original location and resizing the `contentSize` in a way that is hidden from the user. I used the following approach instead.

I simply create a new scrollview, with a limited size, and lay it over the top of my existing one. I move the three views (the one being used and those either side) into this temporary scrollview, adjusting their origin as per Mazyod's answer.

When I need to revert, I simply move the views back into the real scrollview and remove the temporary one.

Not as efficient, but a viable alternative.