# Allow scrolling with content size equal to frame size

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

How can I create a paged `UIScrollView` where the content size only allows one item to be viewed (but there is more content to the left and right, which should be inaccessible)? I want to 'trap' the user on a single page, with bounce-back on either side, similar to the way a paged `UIScrollView` works with only one page of content.

But if I set the content size to the same width as my single page, scrolling is completely disabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To appropriately make any `UIScrollView` always bounce, set its `alwaysBounceHorizontal/Vertical:` property:

```
[_scrollView setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the content size to slightly larger than your frame size should do it. One or two points definitely will; you might even be able to get away with a fractional amount. Either way, your scroll view delegate should handle scrolling the view back to a “centered” content offset when the user releases the scroll view.

Comment: I have to say that your approach is a bit 'hackish'. I answered Ben's question in his other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356680/shrinking-a-uiscrollview. (use `setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:`).

Comment: Please add this as an answer, I agree.

Comment: @BenPackard Fine, since your other question will answer something else, it seems ;)

Answer (score -1):

You could set scrollEnabled to NO, which prevents the scrollview being moved, but that would also prevent the bounces.  I think you'd need to remove the items to the sides and reset the contentSize while the condition that prevents the scrolling is present; then add them back in when that condition clears.